# RDLC Expression counting all rows where value is True

Tags: rdlc

I need to count all the values that are "True", but I have 2 datasets. I saw a lot of tutorials with one dataset and it seems easy because thay can just name the Value and it works.
The thing I tried is this

```
=Count(IIf((Fields!Usvojena.Value, "DataSetTackeDnevnogReda") = "True", 1, Nothing))
```

- Fields!Usvojena.Value returns True or False
- "DataSetTackeDnevnogReda" is the name of my second dataset

I get this error message:

> The Value expression for the textrun
>   ‘Textbox8.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ has a scope parameter that is not
>   valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a
>   string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing
>   group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset.

Also for some reason `Fields!Usvojena.Value` is always underlined with red color in my Expression windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SUM instead of count to eliminate including "Nothing" value (and to get your count anyway) - add one only for those that have Fields!Usvojena.Value = true and zero if it's not. Also, if the field is boolean True/False, then you can do it this way:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Usvojena.Value, 1, 0))
```

If the field is just a string with "True" or "False" values, then you need to add this value to comparison:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Usvojena.Value = "True", 1, 0))
```

As for underlying with red color - check the field name as well.

Comment: Thanks for anwser. I implemented your code with boolean and it worked. But also I made additional error where I implemented all of my code on a textbox that can't work with ReportDataSource content. When I copied it in the tablix cell it worked like a charm. Because of that I had underlying with red color and didn't work.